# OS X 10.8 in a VM on a Mac running Windows

Tags: macos, windows, virtualization

I would like to get Mac OS 10.8 to run out of a VM on a retina MacBook Pro under Windows 8 host.

- Do I need to buy an OS X Server license or can I use the one shipped with the laptop?
- Where do I get the installation media for the clean installation?
- What is the easiest way to get it installed in a VM?
- What is the best virtualization software for this case? I'd prefer VirtualBox, but I don't mind paying if something else provides better compatibility and speed.

Answer (score 2):

The OS X EULA (both client and server editions) restricts running OS X as the guest OS in a VM running on OS X as the host OS. In other words you are only allowed to run OS X in a VM that is itself running on OS X. See section 2-B-iii of the most recently published OS X EULA document for the official wording.  http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf